# Problem in the code of the sum of two numbers using typescript

Tags: html, typescript

Please someone help me understand why this error is appearing in the code?

**The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.ts(2779)**

Print code in typescript:
[image]

Print code in html
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and please don't post [pictures of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9583747).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) on the left side of assignment, which is what the error is saying. Instead of using chaining, you can check that `res` is defined in a standard `if` statement before trying to set it:

```js
if(res) {
  res.innerHTML = calcular()
}
```